# Whats is the difference between index.js and _app.js in NextJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Could someone explain to me what is the difference between index.js file and _app.js? In the Next tutorial it says to change the index.js but what is rendered for me is _app.js.

Comment: I'd recommend a read through the [Custom `App`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app) docs.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`_app.js` will contain your whole app, meaning this will be rendered in any page of the project. Eg. if you add a `<div>hello world</div>` in this file, you will see the Hello World on each and every page of your website. More reading [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app).

`index.js` will only be rendered if you access `/` path of your website. You will use index files whenever you create a new page, for example you want an about page, you will have an about folder containing an `index.js`, all of this contained in the `pages` folder. More reading [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction) .